# Can I store files of different types on one paperclip attachment field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a model that accepts either a photo or video. It works okay, but I think it's getting caught up on the validations.

For photos, I have this:

`has_attached_file :content, styles: { thumb: '275x185#' }`

Which works great, but saving something with a video produces:

`Validation failed: Content Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError, Content Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError`

I think this is because it's trying to size the video's dimensions. Is it possible to only define the thumb size for content that is an image, but ignore it when it is a video? Or do I have to make two different fields, one photo one video, and have nil's in my DB?

Comment: Maybe this will help but i kinda guess you already saw it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149985/use-single-attachment-for-video-image-in-paperclip
EDIT: doesn't address your problem, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`styles` can be given a lambda to perform conditional processing:

```rb
has_attached_file :content, styles: lambda do |a|
  if ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'].include? a.instance.content_content_type
    { thumb: '275x185#'}
  end  
end
```

However, the method used here to check if `content` is an image may be inaccurate.