# Paperclip for both images and Videos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, paperclip, paperclip-validation

In my app I already have paperclip for upload images, but requirement changed in order to accept both images and videos. The images are already defined in a model with a `belongs_to` relationship, called `Attachment`. Since the video will also be an attachment of the same parent model (in my case, articles) I wanted to reuse the same `Attachment` model for images & videos. Is this a good idea?

The code of my  `attachment.rb` is:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :article 

  has_attached_file :url, :s3_protocol => :https , 
    styles: { 
      medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>", big: "1200x1200>", normal: "600x600>" 
    }

  validates_attachment_content_type :url, content_type: /\Aimage|\Avideo\/.*\Z/

  validates_attachment :url, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "video/mp4"] }

end
```

But as it is, it's not storing videos on the S3. I get the following in the terminal

```
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/v_/pf2bsxnj1y37ccd2pjksv7z80000gn/T/f3e2afc957bb9fb2aa3e77e69359c48920160131-13311-pyeez1.mp4'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/v_/pf2bsxnj1y37ccd2pjksv7z80000gn/T/8dc7385648e2164764b72fda6fd9099a20160131-13311-1l40ccn.mp4[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/v_/pf2bsxnj1y37ccd2pjksv7z80000gn/T/8dc7385648e2164764b72fda6fd9099a20160131-13311-1l40ccn.mp4[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/v_/pf2bsxnj1y37ccd2pjksv7z80000gn/T/8dc7385648e2164764b72fda6fd9099a20160131-13311-1l40ccn.mp4[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/v_/pf2bsxnj1y37ccd2pjksv7z80000gn/T/8dc7385648e2164764b72fda6fd9099a20160131-13311-1l40ccn.mp4[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/v_/pf2bsxnj1y37ccd2pjksv7z80000gn/T/f3e2afc957bb9fb2aa3e77e69359c48920160131-13311-kvb5nr.mp4'
```

The second question is since I'm using AngularJS for the frontend, can I just take advantage of HTML `<video>` tag to render the video to the user?

Comment: How are you transcoding the video?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the issue is that `ImageMagick` is trying to [transcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcoding) the video, which it cannot.

The way to handle transcoding of videos within `Paperclip` is to use the [`paperclip-av-transcoder`](https://github.com/ruby-av/paperclip-av-transcoder) gem (formerly [`paperclip-ffmpeg`](https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg)). I only have experience with the latter:

```
#app/models/attachment.rb
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :url, :s3_protocol => :https , 
       styles:  lambda { |a| a.instance.is_image? ?  medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>", big: "1200x1200>", normal: "600x600>" } : {:thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10}, :medium => { :geometry => "300x300#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10}}}, processors: [:transcoder]

    validates_attachment :url,
        content_type: ['video/mp4'],
        message:      "Sorry, right now we only support MP4 video",
        if:           :is_video?

    validates_attachment :url,
        content_type: ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/gif'],
        message:      "Different error message",
        if:           :is_image?

  private

  def is_video?
    url.instance.attachment_content_type =~ %r(video)
  end

  def is_image?
    url.instance.attachment_content_type =~ %r(image)
  end
end
```

[Our old code](https://github.com/joehilton/hpvideos/blob/master/app/models/attachment.rb) & [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7178132/1143732)

Comment: There's two issues with the code above. The first is that there should be a `{`
before the `medium: "300x300>"` to mark the beginning of the hash. The second is
that the `processors: [:transcoder]` flag will run transcoders on all of the
uploads, not just videos, so ffmpeg will fail when you send it an image.